# I running a Simple insertion data to Database then getting error is

Tags: .net

**Error:**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Datab
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection cn;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmb;
        DataSet ds;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection("Server=KAPIL Database=Shiv Login=sa Password=123");
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee", cn);
            cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds,"Employee");

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DDLColumn.Items.Add("Select A Coloumn");

                foreach (DataColumn C in ds.Tables["Employee"].Columns)
                {
                    DDLColumn.Items.Add(C.ToString());
                }
            }
            btnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return Confirm('Do You Want To Dlete')");
        }

        protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Slect isnull(Max(Dept_NO),0)+10 from Employee";
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();

            txtDNo.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            cn.Close();

            txtDName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtLoc.Text = string.Empty;
            txtDName.Focus();
            btnInsert.Enabled = true;
            btnNew.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
            dr[0] = txtDNo.Text;
            dr[1] = txtDName.Text;
            dr[1] = txtLoc.Text;

            ds.Tables["Employee"].Rows.Add(dr);
            da.Update(ds, "Employee");
            lblError.Text = "One row Successfully Inserted";
            btnNew.Enabled = true;
            btnInsert.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no semi-colons in your ConnectionString

Comment: @user..the problem is with your database connection...check whether the database is up and running?

Comment: Also on the `btnNew_Click` event, change 'Slect' to 'Select'.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string like this:

```
 cn=new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword");
```

For different syntaxes refer to:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Comment: Its Working @avinash kothamasu

Comment: @user3256262..PLease mark it as answeer..if it works for you..so that it will be useful for others for future reference..

Comment: @user3256262..In order to mark as answer, click the right mark on the left side of the answer, the accepted answer turns into green color..